# Input element added does not appear on PHP post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have tried to add input text element to my form

through this jquery code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
      counter++;
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="" name="item'+counter+'"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="" name="rate'+counter+'"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="" name="quantity'+counter+'"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("#myTable").append(newRow);
        $("#itemcounter").val(counter);

    });
    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        var count = $("#itemcounter").val();
        $("#itemcounter").val(count-1);
        counter = count -1;
    });


});
```

Now the form is as below:

```
<form action="{{url('/billgenerate')}}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="itemcounter" id="itemcounter" value="">
<table id="myTable" class="table order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Name</td>
            <td>Rate</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" name="item0" class="" style="width:22em" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" name="rate0"  class=""/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" name="quantity0"  class=""/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" name="addrow" id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

when I add add new row, it adds successfully, and also the element is added with its name increment by 1 so that while posting the page the name does not get conflicts.

but when I try to add a input predefined inside the table, php recognizes that particular element.

but when I try to add it through jquery code, it does not return the elements which are added. where am i going wrong?

Comment: Try a button type instead of an input and as an button/submit.

Comment: i tried.. nothing changed

Comment: Could you post the php code that you are using to retrieve the values?

Comment: look at your developer console and use php's error reporting

Comment: m just dumping the data that i've got while submitting the form..no other code in php side. i receive the elements which are already mentioned inside the table

Comment: nevertheless please show how you are dumping the PHP data. Also have you checked your browser's network tab and looked at the HTTP request that submits the form, to see if the values are sent by the client or not? There are some basic debugging steps you can do to pinpoint exactly where the problem is in the pipeline.